# How to retain the value when returned

Tags: javascript, css

is there a way where x and y, when returned, can retain the value that has been inputted instead of being undefined?

Just in case you need the objective of the code here it is:

- Call the function inputNumber to accept 2 values (var x and y turned into int a and b) then call getAverage. Call inputNumber again to input the value for var z turned into int c then call checkInterval.

Here is my code:

```js
var i = 0;
    function inputNumber() {
        if(i == 1){
            var z = prompt("Input the value of c");
            var c = parseInt(z);
            checkInterval(a,b,c);   
        }else{   
            var x = prompt("Input the value of a");
            var y = prompt("Input the value of b");
            return x;
            return y;
        }  
    }

    var a = parseInt(x);    
    var b = parseInt(y);
    getAverage(a,b); 

    function getAverage(a,b) {
        average = (a + b)/2;
        div1.innerHTML = "The average of a and b is " + average;
        i++;
        return i;
    }
    inputNumber();
    function checkInterval(a,b,c) {
        if(a<b && a<c<<b || b<a && b<c<a){
            div2.innerHTML = "c is an interval of a and b";
            alert("TRUE");
        }else{
            div2.innerHTML = "c is not an interval of a and b";
            alert("FALSE");
        }
    }
```

```html
<body onload="inputNumber()">
    <div id="div1"></div>
      <div id="div2"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do NOT post code in images. There's option to post your code in stackoverflow.

Comment: a single function is only return once. so `return x; return y;` will not work as you expect; it only return x. Also `x` and `y` is local variable of function `inputNumber()` which is not visible when calling in global code.

Comment: and also, people is not really like `please help my homework` kind question in stackoverflow

Comment: This is not my homework, I am just trying to learn programming languages.

Comment: @Anonymous can I know why my answer was not approved?

Comment: @Nitheesh Sorry, I thought I could approve more than one answer, but anyway, I will since I think your response is the most helpful.

Comment: @Anonymous you can approve only one answer for a question. But you can upvote multiple answers within a question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your solution with my interpretation.

Some issues that I identified in your code.

- A javascript function cannot return more that one value. In that scenario, you have to go for returning a javascript object.
- Also there was some issue in your comparison logic in `checkInterval` function, I have implemented my own logic there.

```js
var i = 0;
const div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
const div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
const { x, y } = inputNumber();
function inputNumber() {
  if (i == 1) {
    var z = prompt("Input the value of c");
    var c = parseInt(z);
    checkInterval(a, b, c);
  } else {
    var x = prompt("Input the value of a");
    var y = prompt("Input the value of b");
    i++;
    return {
      x: x,
      y: y,
    }
  }
}

var a = parseInt(x);
var b = parseInt(y);
getAverage(a, b);
function getAverage(a, b) {
  average = (a + b) / 2;
  div1.innerHTML = "The average of a and b is " + average;
  return i;
}
inputNumber();
function checkInterval(a, b, c) {
  if ((a < c && c < b) || (b < c && c < a)) {
    div2.innerHTML = "c is an interval of a and b";
    alert("TRUE");
  } else {
    div2.innerHTML = "c is not an interval of a and b";
    alert("FALSE");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables `x` and `y` are function scoped so they are available only within the function where they are defined. So, you need to define it in the outer scope so that all functions have access to it. See the code snippet below, it should help!

Also, avoid using `innerHTML` use `innerText` or `textContent` instead.

```js
var x;
function demo() {
  x = prompt("Enter a number");
  after();
}

function after() {
  alert("Your number is " + x);
}
```

```html
<body onload="demo()">
</body>
```